# Cython: parallel computing

Tags: python-3.x, cython

as of today, I have been able to compile my codes with Cython and speed up my programs. Now, I would like to learn parallel computing but since I am new to this I am trying simple examples first and I was trying to implement the one given [here](http://nealhughes.net/parallelcomp2/). When I compile my `setup.py` using the following code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension('test_multi',
              ['test_multi.pyx'],
              libraries=['m'],
              extra_compile_args = ['-O3', '-ffast-math', '-march=native', '-fopenmp' ],
              extra_link_args=['-fopenmp']
              )
]
setup(cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext}, ext_modules=ext_modules)
```

the compiler is warning me that it does not recognize `'-O3', '-ffast-math', '-march=native', '-fopenmp'` and the compile command is failing. I also tried to modify `ext_modules` as defined [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html):

```
ext_modules = [
    Extension(
       'test_multi',
        ['test_multi.pyx'],
        extra_compile_args=['/openmp'],
        extra_link_args=['/openmp'],
    )
]
```

but also in this case, `'/openmp'` is not recognized.

What am I missing? I tried to have a look around but I was not able to find an answer (or at least if there was one, I did not get it). Could you please help me? If you need some extra info, please ask me. Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio Build Tools 2019.

**EDIT 2:** the warning I get is `LNK4044:unrecognized option '/openmp'; ignored`.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: `-O3`, `-march=native` and `-ffast-math` are gcc or clang compiler flags. Since you're using Windows, I guess you use MVSC?

Comment: DavidW and joni, thanks for your reply. Please see the edit in my question

Comment: You probably want the `/openmp` version. The full error message would probably be helpful (rather than just your one-line summary). It's possible that there's some useful detail in it.

Comment: @DavidW Please, see EDIT 2

Comment: MSVC doesn’t need this flag, but it is only a warning - the compiled extension must be there